# layout nullpointerexception in asynctask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I am updating my fragments ui's from onPostExecute running on the ui thread.  I have a nullpointerException within my `onPostExecute()` asynctask method.

Here is what is within my method:

```
// dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {



                 //TODO fill front-end
                //all
                //get view for each fragment.
                for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++){
                    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + mViewPager.getId() + ":" + i);
                    View view = fragment.getView();

                    TableLayout layout;
                    switch(i){

                    /* Update parsed JSON data into tablelayouts
                     */

                    case 0:
                        //allcontent
                        layout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.AllContentLayout);

                        for(JsonInObject item: allItems){
                            if(item.getType().equals("text")){
                                addText(layout, item);
                            }else{
                                addImage(layout, item);
                            }
                        }

                        break;

                    case 1:    //Error take place within this from this for loop.
                        //text
                        layout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.TextContentLayout);

                        for(Textobj item: textBlocks){
                            addText(layout, item);
                        }

                        break;

                    case 2:
                        //images
                        layout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageContentLayout);

                        for(Imageobj item: images){
                            addImage(layout, item);
                        }

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

This is the addText method stated within the error:

```
    private void addText(TableLayout textLayout, JsonInObject item){
    //build the rows and add them to the fragment view
    //TableRow newrow = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableTextRow);
    TableRow newrow = new TableRow(ContentActivity.this);
    newrow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView nameText = new TextView(ContentActivity.this);
    nameText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //TextView nametext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

    if(item.setIsComplete() != false){
        try{
            nameText.setText(item.getData());
        } catch(NullPointerException e){
            Log.println(1, "NULLPOINTER", "Either the tablerow, Texview or tablelayout is null... for some reason.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

            newrow.addView(nameText);

        textLayout.addView(newrow);
    }
}
```

Here is my error:

```
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at com.eddiecubed44.Jsonapptest.ContentActivity.addText(ContentActivity.java:448)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at com.eddiecubed44.Jsonapptest.ContentActivity.access$3(ContentActivity.java:426)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at com.eddiecubed44.Jsonapptest.ContentActivity$LoadTextnImgs$1.run(FuzzContentActivity.java:355)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4631)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at com.eddiecubed44.Jsonapptest.ContentActivity$LoadTextnImgs.onPostExecute(ContentActivity.java:318)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at com.eddiecubed44.Jsonapptest.ContentActivity$LoadTextnImgs.onPostExecute(ContentActivity.java:1)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
10-19 11:39:36.706: E/AndroidRuntime(32637):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The nullpointer is associated with he layout that i am using to add the tablerows to.  I am at a loss why this is turning null. The line number that the error is happening on is within `case 1:` And as you can see, I have used the layout before in `case 0:` and I am assuming that the rows were added correctly.

help me obi wan kenobi you're my only hope.

Comment: first `onPostExecute` is invoked on the ui thread. so runOnUithread is not required. second what is line 448 `ContentActivity.java`

Comment: where you are initializing `nameText` and `textLayout` Views?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK `private void addText(TableLayout textLayout, JsonInObject item){` for `TableLayout textLayout` and `TextView nameText = new TextView(FuzzContentActivity.this)` for `nameText` and op has  `addText(layout, item)`

Comment: What line is : `ContentActivity.java:448`

Comment: line 448 is textLayout.addView(newrow);

Comment: Any suggestions?  I have gotten close to no where with this problem.  I've tried changing how i retrieve the Fragments view from the fragmentpageradapter.